# Selected field only some users

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a Tasks model. One of its fields is status.

How can I make the NEW and COMPLITED statuses be selected only by the author of the task, while these statuses were not available to performers?

models.py

```
class Tasks(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICE = (
        ('new', 'new'),
        ('in progress', 'in progress'),
        ('on finish', 'on finish'),
        ('completed', 'completed')
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    text = models.TextField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=STATUS_CHOICE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    performers = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='performers')
    date_create = models.DateField(default=now)
    date_update = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class TasksSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    author = SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='username')
    performers = SlugRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, slug_field='username')
   
    class Meta:
        model = Tasks
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class TasksViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsPerformers]
    queryset = Tasks.objects.all()
                .select_related('author')
                .prefetch_related('performers')
    serializer_class = TasksSerializer

    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter, OrderingFilter]
    filterset_fields = ['status']
    search_fields = ['title', 'text']
    ordering_fields = ['date_create', 'date_update', 'author', 'status']
```

Can you tell me how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

What I think might work is check for this in your ModelViewSet:

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import PermissionDenied

class TasksViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    # ...

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        task = self.get_object()
        if task.status != request.data.get('status') and request.user != task.author:
            raise PermissionDenied('You are not allowed to change the status of this task')
        return super().update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

self.get_object() will get the current state of the object in the database. Then we compare that to the status we received in the API call, if they don't match we check whether the request.user == author